# Tangent at the pole for the equation $r = 2(1 - \sin\theta)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

I was asked to find the tangents at the pole for the following equation: $r=2(1-\sin\theta)$.

I understand that the requirements for tangency at the pole are $f(\theta)=0$ and $f'(\theta) \neq 0$. I set $0=2(1-\sin\pi)$ and got $\theta= \frac{\pi}{2}$. But when I plugged that into the derivative, I got $f'(\theta)=0$. Why is that? Am I solving it wrong? (By the way, my $f'$ was $f'(\theta)=-2\cos\theta$). Thank You!

Comment: What is f??????

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You meant to write $2(1 - \sin\theta) = 0 \implies \theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

You calculated the derivative incorrectly.  The derivative is
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\dfrac{dy}{d\theta}}{\dfrac{dx}{d\theta}}$$
where
\begin{align*}
x & = r\cos\theta\\
y & = r\sin\theta
\end{align*}
By the product rule,
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{d\theta} & = r'\cos\theta - r\sin\theta\\
\frac{dy}{d\theta} & = r'\sin\theta + r\cos\theta
\end{align*}
where
$$r' = \frac{dr}{d\theta}$$
Hence,
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{r'\sin\theta + r\cos\theta}{r'\cos\theta - r\sin\theta}$$
We were given the function $r(\theta) = 2(1 - \sin\theta)$.  At the pole, $r = 0$, so we obtain
\begin{align*}
2(1 - \sin\theta) & = 0\\
1 - \sin\theta & = 0\\
1 & = \sin\theta\\
\frac{\pi}{2} & = \theta
\end{align*}
Notice that at the pole, since $r = 0$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx} & = \frac{r'\sin\theta + r\cos\theta}{r'\cos\theta - r\sin\theta}\\
              & = \frac{r'\sin\theta}{r'\cos\theta}\\
              & = \tan\theta
\end{align*}
Observe that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}^-} \tan\theta & = \infty\\
\lim_{\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}^+} \tan\theta & = -\infty
\end{align*}
Thus, the function $r(\theta) = 2(1 - \sin\theta)$ has a cusp at the pole, as can be seen from viewing its graph, which is a cardioid.

[image: polar_graph_of_cardioid]